# No json data being returned, when URL contains data

Tags: php, json, api

I built a very basic webAPI that when called prints some json data on the screen.

I'm calling the api with the following

```
function getEnvironmentList(){
    $fullUrl = "localhost/serverList/api/rest.php?action=allenvironments&format=json";
    $jsonDataRaw = file_get_contents($fullUrl);
    return $jsonDataRaw;
}
$jsonData = getEnvironmentList();
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump(json_decode($jsonData, true));
echo "</PRE>";
```

I get the error `Warning: file_get_contents(localhost/serverList/api/rest.php?action=allenvironments&format=json): failed to open stream: No error in C:\path\inc\getJSONdata.php on line 6`

Yet when I visit that URL I see this

```
{"1":{"environmentID":"1","envName":"UAT","envCreatedBy":"mhopkins","envCreatedDtTm":"2013-06-30 00:34:57","envUpdatedBy":"mhopkins","envUpdatedDtTm":"2013-06-30 00:34:57"},"3":{"environmentID":"3","envName":"Platinum","envCreatedBy":"mhopkins","envCreatedDtTm":"2013-06-30 00:37:38","envUpdatedBy":"phpsense","envUpdatedDtTm":"2013-06-30 00:37:38"}}
```

I'm really confused why the code can't seem to realize there is json data there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `http`.

```
$fullUrl = "http://localhost/serverList/api/rest.php?action=allenvironments&format=json";
```

Comment: yup, that would be it. I guess I just figured if I could copy/paste it and see data, the computer would too. PHP is finicky! Thanks!

Comment: countdown timer is on 11 minutes. I will once it hits 0